# Why aren't arrow keys working in my VS Code Jupyter Notebook using the Jupyter extension's v2023.3?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I am having a weird problem. When I edit a Jupyter Notebook for a while, the arrow keys would suddenly stop working for a particular cell. However, the CTRL-arrow keys and all other keys would continue to work. Further, other cells are not affected.

One cumbersome workaround is creating a new cell and copying and pasting the contents from the affected cell. As you see, this is highly inconvenient.

I feel like VS Code gets into some odd state, but I don't know how to escape it. I would appreciate it if anyone knew how to recover from this.

Comment: possibly related IPython issue: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/14051#issuecomment-1528787096

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an answer here:  https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/13263#issuecomment-1495291228.  I found an extension (Kite) showing an error (in the OUTPUT window).  I disabled Kite and all is good for me so far and the problem has not returned.  Of course if you really need an extension that is giving this type of error you would obviously need to correct the problem instead of just disabling the extension.

Comment: Ah, that was exactly what I was looking for. I was thinking there has to be a way to trace the events.

Comment: After removing the key combinations for `editor.action.scrollLeftHover` and similarly also for up, down, and right, the arrows keys started working :)

Answer (score 9):

This suggestion from https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/13263 solved it ror me, just add the following to the keyboard shortcuts json:

```json
    { "key": "down", "command": "-editor.action.scrollDownHover", "when": "editorHoverFocused" },
    { "key": "left", "command": "-editor.action.scrollLeftHover", "when": "editorHoverFocused" },
    { "key": "right", "command": "-editor.action.scrollRightHover", "when": "editorHoverFocused" },
    { "key": "up", "command": "-editor.action.scrollUpHover", "when": "editorHoverFocused" },
    { "key": "home", "command": "-editor.action.goToTopHover", "when": "editorHoverFocused" },
    { "key": "end", "command": "-editor.action.goToBottomHover", "when": "editorHoverFocused" },
```

Comment: does the - mean "disable this command " ?

Comment: @userrandrand Yes. The minus sign on the command means disable. Personally I would suggest you add ``&& resourceExtname != '.ipynb'`` to the when string instead, as this will prevent the keybinding only for extension .ipynb instead of disabling completely. This logic can be applied to any ext for any command.

Answer (score 2):

**Just cut and paste the broken cells' contents into new cells. Seems to work every time.**

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out using @vtt's method. It turns out that when this happens, VSCode incorrectly thinks it is in hover mode. It is possible to force it back into the correct state when this problem happens by deliberately entering the hover mode by pressing CTRL-K CTRL-I and then exiting it. Sometimes it must be repeated a few times to get back the arrow keys.

Answer (score 1):

You can execute the command "Developer: Reload Window". It's the quickest thing to do until they fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know why this occurs but you can solve this issue reloading the window:

1. CTRL + SHIFT + P
2. Developer: Reload Window

Comment: Helped me to recover from this bug.

Answer (score 0):

Collapse and un-collapse the cell.

No idea why i have this issue since i dont have kite but the above worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me it happened because there were few messages in the Problems tab( some errors regarding pandas and numpy). I cleared the errors(deleted code with numpy and pandas) and this fixed the issue

Answer (score -1):

Copy and paste into a new cell works. I don't have Kite and I experience a similar problem.